# Can't install the `imager` package on Windows

Tags: r, libtiff

I'm trying to install the `ìmager` package on a Windows computer, but I'm getting an error. It isn't finding `tiffio.h`. I have no experience to Windows, but I think maybe I should install some kind of library (googling didn't make this any clearer)? How can I install the files that are missing and install the package?

The error I get is below:

```
* installing *source* package 'imager' ...
** package 'imager' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

   **********************************************
   WARNING: this package has a configure script
         It probably needs manual configuration
   **********************************************


** libs

*** arch - i386
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS -Dcimg_use_r -DCIMG_COMPILING -Dcimg_use_fftw3_singlethread -Dcimg_use_tiff  -Dcimg_use_rng -Dcimg_verbosity=1 -fpermissive -I/include -I/include -fopenmp -I"C:/Users/victo/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:0:
../inst/include/imager.h:4:0: warning: "STRICT_R_HEADERS" redefined
 #define STRICT_R_HEADERS
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from ../inst/include/imager.h:26:0,
                 from RcppExports.cpp:4:
../inst/include/CImg.h:451:20: fatal error: tiffio.h: No such file or directory
 #include "tiffio.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'imager'
```

Comment: Have a look at the project [home page](https://github.com/dahtah/imager), it has installation instructions.

Comment: Did you ever solve this, @Freguglia?

Comment: Yes, I installed the binary package instead.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the instructions above, you need the "[local tree](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/Rtools/libs.html)" for Rtools to be able to build imager.

Only the headers should be required, so just extract the include folder inside `mingw_32\i686-w64-mingw32` and/or `mingw_64\x86_64-w64-mingw32` in the Rtools directory.