# How can I install packages like imager?

Tags: r, image, imager

I've been trying to install the [imager package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=imager) and I keep getting the same error:

```
* installing *source* package 'imager' ...
** package 'imager' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation

   **********************************************
   WARNING: this package has a configure script
         It probably needs manual configuration
   **********************************************


** libs

*** arch - i386
/mingw32/bin/g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS -Dcimg_use_r -DCIMG_COMPILING -Dcimg_use_fftw3_singlethread -Dcimg_use_tiff  -Dcimg_use_rng -Dcimg_verbosity=1 -fpermissive -I/include -I/include  -I'C:/Users/Mikael/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/Rcpp/include'     -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
In file included from ../inst/include/imager.h:27,
                 from RcppExports.cpp:4:
../inst/include/CImg.h:459:10: fatal error: tiffio.h: No such file or directory
 #include "tiffio.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf:229: RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'imager'
* removing 'C:/Users/Mikael/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/imager'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘imager’ had non-zero exit status
```

Not sure how to go about fixing this?

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50614348/cant-install-the-imager-package-on-windows)  can help.

Comment: just install the binary

Comment: Please edit to include:  your OS, how you are installing ("install.packages" ? Local source package? local binary?),

Comment: I think @RuiBarradas is right - other folks please close this as a Duplicate.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Not possible, the only answer is not upvoted nor accepted.